# advanced calculus lagrange multipliers

Tags: calculus

Consider the sphere S with equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2$, and let $P(a,b,c)$ be any
point other than the origin. Let $Q1$ be the point on S closest to $P$, and let $Q2$ be
the point on S furthest from $P$.

(a) By applying the method of Lagrange multipliers to a suitable function of
three variables, find the coordinates of $Q1$ and $Q2$.

(b) Let $R = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}$. Show that $|PQ1|=|r-R|$ and $|PQ2|=r+R$

(c) Draw a diagram and explain in words why the answer to the previous question is to be expected.

Answer (score 2):

Your objective function is most conveniently taken to be $f(x,y,z) = (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2+(z-c)^2$ subject the constraint $g(x,y,z) = x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$. So, set $\nabla f = \lambda \nabla g$ and work it out.

Comment: i got up to some point where i got x=-a am i on the right track? cause im not sure

Comment: well, I would expect equations such as $2(x-a) = 2\lambda x$ and the same for $y$ and $z$ with $b,c$ in place of $a$. So, you don't care about $\lambda$, divide the equations to eliminate $\lambda$ then this will allow you to replace $x,y,z$ with just one variable. Also, if you think about the geometry of the problem, sketch a two-dimensional version... the answer is obvious.